# Raspberry Pi controlled remotely by LAN but using alternate internet connection

Tags: connection, internet, android

My Windows laptop connects wirelessly to a LAN (with internet). My Raspberry Pi 3 B+ is wired to the same LAN. I can control the Pi from the Windows laptop using AnyDesk (remote desktop software).

Now I want the Pi never to use the internet from the LAN and instead use internet from an Android phone connected to it via a USB lead. Is this possible?

Comment: Modern routers can deny internet access of defined IP's

Comment: We have to reconfigure the default route on your raspi. To achieve this we have to know the current settings. Please can edit your question and add the output of `ip route` before connecting the Android phone and afterwards? And please address me with @Ingo.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable USB tethering on your Android device, it **should be** (don't know for sure) visible as a network device on the rpi. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_yhJ_QBfaU

Comment: I have that working. But how do you ensure that the PI does not use the Internet from the LAN even though it's attached to and controlled through the LAN?

Comment: You would have to check the routing to see what the default gateway (or routing in general) is. `ip route show`